# Pusher: Trigger pusher events from android app

Tags: android, pusher

In an android app I was able to subscribe to a pusher channel and log out the event data. So now I want to be able to trigger events from the same application. I don't find documentation relating to this on the web.

Am I missing something because I also have a node express app in which I'm able to trigger and subscribe to events in the same app.

Below is my code for the Android app, I'm looking to trigger an event in the "responseAFunc" function which is wired to a button click.

I have also left out the all import statements and package statements.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button responseA;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private Pusher pusher;
    private Channel channel;       

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        responseA = binding.responseA;

        PusherOptions options = new PusherOptions();
        options.setCluster("eu");

        pusher = new Pusher("*****************",options);

        pusher.connect( new ConnectionEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionStateChange(ConnectionStateChange change) {
                Log.e("Pusher"," changed to " + change.getCurrentState());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String message, String code, Exception e) {
                Log.e("Pusher" ," connecting! msg:" + message + " " + code);
                Log.e("Pusher", e.getMessage());
            }
        }, ConnectionState.ALL);

        channel = pusher.subscribe("to-pusher");

        channel.bind("message", new SubscriptionEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(PusherEvent event) {
                Log.i("Pusher", event.getData());
            }
        });
    }

   public void responseAFunc(View view){
        // Trigger event
   }
}
```

Hope this makes sense and HELLO from South Africa !!!

Answer (score 0):

Hello from Amsterdam!

What you are looking for is "client events". Here are the docs: https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/events/#triggering-client-events

It's very easy: Once you got an instance for a channel you can just call the "trigger" method on it. Here are the docs for java: https://github.com/pusher/pusher-websocket-java#triggering-events

The harder part is that it will only work on private and presence channels. And then you will need to implement authentication. https://pusher.com/docs/channels/server_api/authenticating-users/

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will investigate. I have been able to push messages but using Retrofit that send a post to a node js server which then triggers the event.

Comment: Hello there, I have channel authorizer and also used private channel but the trigger() is not sending any message, what can be the issue with it ? Though I am receving messages for all events.